# I have got an error related to JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, web-deployment

I have got an error which is 'JSON cannot be parsed'. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

```
function aj() {
    $('#accounting').dataTable({
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        "bSort": true,
        'bDestroy': true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        'sPaginationType': "full_numbers",
        'iDisplayLength': 25,
        'sAjaxSource': 'admin/datatables/accounting/ledger.php?userID=' + $('#users').val(),
        'aoColumns': [
            { 'mData': 'count' },
            { 'mData': 'AccountID' },
            { 'mData': 'Debit' },
            { 'mData': 'Credit' },
            { 'mData': 'CurrencyID' },
            { 'mData': 'Date' },
            { 'mData': 'Terms' },
            { "mData": 'Actions' }
        ]
    });
}
```

```html
<select onchange="aj();" id="users">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
        $Acc = new BLL\Accounts;
        $Acc->get($arrayOfObjects);
        if (!empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
            foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $value) {
                echo "<option value=" . $value->getID() . "> " . $value->getAccountName() . "</option>";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

the ledger.php is

```
<?php
require_once '../../../layers/loader.php';
require_once '../../../includes/config.php';
require_once '../../../includes/session.php';
if ((isset($_SESSION['sess_staffid'])and $_SESSION['sess_staffid']!="" )) {
  $StaffID = $_SESSION['sess_staffid'];
} else {
    header("Location:" . SITE_URL . "/404.html");
    exit;
}
global $TablePrefix;

$aColumns = array('ID', 'Date', 'Terms', 'AccountID', 'Amount', 'CurrencyID', 'TypeAccount');
//  
//  /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "ID";
//  
//  /* DB table to use */
 $sTable = $TablePrefix . 'general_ledger';

//  
//  /* Database connection information */
//  $gaSql['user']       = 'root';
//  $gaSql['password']   ='' ;
//  $gaSql['db']         = 'mowena';
//  $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
//$mySQL = new MySQL(); 
//        $mySQL = new DAL\Database\MySQL();

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/*
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error($sErrorMessage = '') {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error');
    die($sErrorMessage);
}

/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if (isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1') {
    $sLimit = "LIMIT " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['iDisplayStart']) . ", " .
            mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['iDisplayLength']);
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
//  $sOrder = "ORDER BY CourierID DESC ";
if (isset($_GET['iSortCol_0'])) {
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < intval($_GET['iSortingCols']); $i++) {
        if ($_GET['bSortable_' . intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] == "true") {
            $iColumnIndex = array_search($_GET['mDataProp_' . $_GET['iSortCol_' . $i]], $aColumns);
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[$iColumnIndex] . "
                    " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSortDir_' . $i]) . ", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace($sOrder, "", -2);
    if ($sOrder == "ORDER BY") {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY ID DESC";
    }
}
$sOrder = "ORDER BY ID DESC";

/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if (isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "") {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        if (isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true") {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch']) . "%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
    if (isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_' . $i] != '') {
        if ($sWhere == "") {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        } else {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $iColumnIndex = array_search($_GET['mDataProp_' . $i], $aColumns);
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$iColumnIndex] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_' . $i]) . "%' ";
    }
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['userID']) and $_REQUEST['userID']!=''){
 $sWhere=" WHERE AccountID=".$_REQUEST['userID'];   
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */

 $sQuery1 = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns)) . "
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
$rResult = mysql_query($sQuery1) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query($sQuery) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(" . $sIndexColumn . ")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query($sQuery) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);


$count = $_GET['iDisplayStart'] + 1;
while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)) {
    $row = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        if ($aColumns[$i] == 'Date') {
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime($aRow['Date']));
        } elseif ($aColumns[$i] == 'Active') {
            if ($aRow[$aColumns[$i]] == 'Y')
                $row[$aColumns[$i]] = 'Yes';
            else
                $row[$aColumns[$i]] = 'NO';
        }elseif ($aColumns[$i] == 'Terms') {
            if(!empty($aRow['Terms'])){
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = "<textarea style='width:220px;height:50px'>".$aRow['Terms']."</textarea>";}
            else{
                $row[$aColumns[$i]]="---";
            }
        }elseif (!empty($aColumns[$i])) {
            /* General output */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = '<font>' . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . ' </font>';
        }
    }



    $AccountID = $aRow[AccountID];

    $account = new BLL\Accounts;
    $account->setID($AccountID);
    $account->get($arrayOfacc);
    if (!empty($arrayOfacc)) {
        $arrayOfacc = $arrayOfacc[0];
        $row['AccountID'] = "<a href='user-account.php?accountid=".$aRow[AccountID]."'>".$arrayOfacc->getAccountName()."</a>";
    }
    $Currency = new BLL\Currency();
    $Currency->setCurrencyID($aRow[CurrencyID]);
    $Currency->get($arrayOfCurr);
    if (!empty($arrayOfCurr)) {
        $arrayOfCurr = $arrayOfCurr[0];
        $row['CurrencyID'] = $arrayOfCurr->getCurrencyCode();
    }
    $AccountType = $aRow[TypeAccount];
    switch ($AccountType) {
        case 0:
            $row['Debit'] = $aRow[Amount];
            $row['Credit'] = '-';
            break;
        case 1:
            $row['Credit'] = $aRow[Amount];
            $row['Debit'] = '-';
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    $row['Actions'] = '<a id="edittr'.$aRow[ID].'" onclick="edit_ledger(' .$aRow[ID]. ')"> Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="user-account.php?accountid='.$aRow[AccountID].'">view all</a>';
    $row['count'] = '<font size=2>' . $count++ . '</font>';

    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}//deal_paymentstatus($aRow[paymentstatus])

//echo json_encode($output);
//        var_dump($output);
?>
```

'JSON cannot be parsed'. This is caused by a JSON 
[image]
Can you guide me what should I do to correct it?

----------------------------------------------Error happend

After I have changed some part of JSON which is suggested

```
aoColumns = [
{"mData":"count"},{"mData":"AccountID"},
{"mData":"Debit"},{"mData":"Credit"},
{ "mData": "CurrencyID"},
{"mData":"Date"},
{"mData":"Terms"},
{"mData":"Actions"}
]
```

The following part of code does not work

```
<div class="DTED_Lightbox_Content"  id="DTED_Lightbox_Content1"  tabindex="-1" style="width: 40%;display: none;position:absolute;top:25%;left:25%;z-index: 1000" >
    <h1>amir</h1>
    <div class="DTE DTE_Action_Create">
        <div data-dte-e="processing" class="DTE_Processing_Indicator"  id="DTE_Processing_Indicator1" style="display:none"></div>
        <div data-dte-e="head" class="DTE_Header">
            <div data-dte-e="head_content" class="DTE_Header_Content">Edit Account Group </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dte-e="body" class="DTE_Body">
            <div data-dte-e="body_content" class="DTE_Body_Content" style="height: 400px;">
                <form data-dte-e="form" class="" style="display: block;">
                    <div data-dte-e="form_content" class="DTE_Form_Content">
                        <div id="peymethod1">
                            <table>
                                <tr><td>Account Name:</td><td><select id="account_name1">
                                            <option value="">Select account name </option>
                                            <?php
                                            $Acc = new BLL\Accounts;
                                            $Acc->get($arrayOfObjects);
                                            if (!empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
                                                foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $value) {
                                                    echo "<option value=" . $value->getID() . "> " . $value->getAccountName() . "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="date3" value="" name="account-date"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Amount:</td><td><input type="text"  value="" name="account-amount" id="amount1"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Account Type:</td><td><select id="account_type1">
                                            <option value="">Select account Type</option>
                                            <option value="0">Debit</option>
                                            <option value="1">Credit</option>
                                        </select></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Currency:</td><td><select id="currency1">
                                            <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                            <option value="2">EUR</option>
                                            <option value="1">USD</option>
                                        </select></td></tr> 
                                <tr><td>term:</td><td><textarea name="account_term" id="term1"></textarea></td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="">
                            <div data-dte-e="input" class=""> 
                                <div data-dte-e="msg-message" class="DTE_Field_Message"></div>
                                <div data-dte-e="msg-info" class="DTE_Field_Info"></div></div>
                        </div> 
                        <div data-dte-e="form_error" class="DTE_Form_Error" id="DTE_Form_Error1" style="display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div data-dte-e="form_clear" class="DTE_Form_Clear" id="DTE_Form_Clear1"></div>
                    </div></form></div>
        </div>
        <div data-dte-e="foot" class="DTE_Footer">
            <div data-dte-e="foot_content" class="DTE_Footer_Content">
                <div data-dte-e="form_buttons" class="DTE_Form_Buttons" id="DTE_Form_Buttons1"><button class="butt">Update</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Gid" id="Gid" value=""/>  </div></div></div></div>
    <div class="DTED_Lightbox_Close" id="DTED_Lightbox_Close1" ></div></div>




<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="display: none;z-index: 1;width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>


<?php
require_once 'footer.php';
?><br />
```

Any one can guide?

Comment: You forgot to mention at which line you get the error? What is the error?

Comment: Can you show us the response of **ledger.php**

Comment: if `users` is a list of  users, you may need to use something like `selectedIndex` instead of `val`

Comment: @RST `val()` will work fine

Comment: As others have said, you need to check the console to see if the request worked and its state, and also we need to see the code of `ledger.php` and also the format of the JSON response in order to help you.

Comment: Your PHP is not returning JSON as you have commented out the `json_encode` line. What happens when you uncomment that?

Comment: nothing happend same as before :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aoColumns json format is wrong Please remove spaces and use the following format :

```
aoColumns = [
{"mData":"count"},{"mData":"AccountID"},
{"mData":"Debit"},{"mData":"Credit"},
{ "mData": "CurrencyID"},
{"mData":"Date"},
{"mData":"Terms"},
{"mData":"Actions"}
]
```

Comment: Whitespace makes zero difference in the formatting of an object. Logically this and what the OP has is identical.

Comment: That has no relation to the object you provide to the columns in this case, and even less relevance to the whitespace within that object.

Comment: Dear @RutushaJoshi I have done your suggestion. However, some part of the code is not working!?! can you guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'sAjaxSource' url must contain json encode data

Use http://jsonlint.com/  to validate json data

Version which work fine for me :

jquery-1.7.1, 
   jquery.dataTables 1.9.0

Comment: This is completely wrong; the property should be a string with a URL. See the `sAjaxSource` entry in the documentation: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: Please chk : JSOn object should be passed

  You can instruct DataTables to load data from an external source using this parameter (use aData if you want to pass data in you already have). Simply provide a url a JSON object can be obtained from. This object must include the parameter 'aaData' which is the data source for the table.

Comment: Exactly, so `sAjaxSource` should be a string, not JSON encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be this part:  + $('#users').val()

When i leave this out, the json format seems valid if i check it with an online json reader (i used http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ but there are many).

The reason *probably* is that you can not add in javascript/jquery code within a json string.